# SQL cross-join query not working as intended

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that selects a handful of columns from table 1, *aka* `t1`. I would like to cross join this query with another column from table 2, `t2`, labelled as `employees`

I use `placeholders` for my parameter. For my case, a list of companies for the query to pull for.

```
  sql = f'''SELECT t1.id, cast(t1.enterprisevalue as money), ROUND(t1.enterprise_value_revenue, 2),
       ROUND(t1.revenuepershare, 2), 
       ROUND(t1.debt_to_equity, 2), 
       ROUND(t1.profitmargin, 2), 
       ROUND(t1.price_to_sales, 2), 
       ROUND(t1.price_to_book, 2), 
       ROUND(t1.put_call_ratio, 2), 
       t2.employees, 
       cast(ROUND(t1.revenue_per_employee, 2) as money)
        FROM security_advanced_stats as t1
        cross join (
        select *
        from security_stats as t2
        WHERE id IN ({placeholders})
        order by id
        limit 1) as t2;'''
```

The query doesn't throw errors and does almost everything right, except it's pulling every company in my dB for `t1` data and ignoring the `placeholders` parameter. Could use some evaluation here to help me fix this query. Maybe I'm overcomplicating it somehow...

Comment: If the type of `placeholders` is `ARRAY`, you can use `WHERE id = ANY(placeholders)`. A `CROSS JOIN` is meant to join all rows in `t1` to all rows in `t2`. Are you sure you don't want a `LATERAL JOIN`? Or is your `WHERE` clause meant to be applied to `t1`?

Comment: Placeholders is a string. So even if im limiting my query of rows, using `CROSS JOIN` is redundant here? Never heard of `LATERAL JOIN`, how would that translate to my query? Just replace the cross join?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of `placeholders` explain the intent of the `CROSS JOIN` please? I'll provide an example of the `LATERAL` in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `security_stats` query may return the smaller set out of the two queries. Let's start with that. Then for each record in that return set, find all of the money information.

```
SELECT t2.employees
     , t1.*
  FROM security_stats t2
     , LATERAL
     (
        SELECT sas.id
             , sas.enterprisevalue::MONEY                AS enterprisevalue
             , ROUND(sas.enterprise_value_revenue, 2)    AS enterprise_value_revenue
             , ROUND(sas.revenuepershare, 2)             AS revenuepershare
             , ROUND(sas.debt_to_equity, 2)              AS debt_to_equity     
             , ROUND(sas.profitmargin, 2)                AS profitmargin    
             , ROUND(sas.price_to_sales, 2)              AS price_to_sales
             , ROUND(sas.price_to_book, 2                AS price_to_book     
             , ROUND(sas.put_call_ratio, 2)              AS put_call_ratio
             , ROUND(sas.revenue_per_employee, 2)::MONEY AS revenue_per_employee
          FROM security_advanced_stats sas
     ) t1 
 WHERE t2.id IN ({placeholders})
;
```

---

It's a little hard to tell how `t1` is related to `t2`. It seems like you're looking for a 1 to many relationship between the two. `security_advanced_stats` doesn't hold a foreign key to `security_stats`? Also, why pass a list of `placeholders` and then limit it to 1?